# Python :Read and assign name to sheet in Excels

Tags: excel, pandas

I have an Excel files with multiple sheets named: a,b,c,d,e.....,z
I can read sheet a using following code

```
xl=pd.ExcelFile(r'path.xlsx')
a=xl.parse('a')
```

How can I assign the names of sheets:a,b,c...,z as dataframe names so that I can easily call it later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create `dict` of `DataFrames` by `dict comprehension`:

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile(r'path.xlsx')
print (xl.parse('a'))
   a  b
0  1  2

print (xl.sheet_names)
['a', 'b', 'c']

dfs = {sheet: xl.parse(sheet) for sheet in xl.sheet_names}
print (dfs)
{'a':    a  b
0  1  2, 'b':    b  c
0  5  5, 'c':    r  t
0  7  8}

print (dfs['a'])
   a  b
0  1  2

print (dfs['b'])
   b  c
0  5  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. But is there any way that all I need to do is call: print a